# React Native Ignite CLI 2 - Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native

I keep getting this error when I used Ignite CLI andross to initialize my project. I already did `npm install` but it still throws the error. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you testing in iOS or android? Please try to killall node and rerun the yarn and run the project again.

Comment: I'm testing in iOS

Comment: Try to run: npm i react-native-gesture-handler --save